# Should/could the 'Oops! Something Bad Happened' page be more helpful?

Tags: discussion

Having just got the 'Oops! Something Bad Happened' page when submitting an answer my thought was to resubmit.
Could the error page include text to indicate if this is an appropriate action to take in this instance?

Comment: Didn't the lolcat tell you what to do?

Comment: @Jon I think it is stalking me http://img135.imageshack.us/img135/3457/purplzhy5.jpg

Comment: Thanks for comments all.  I was after something a bit more helpful than <paraphrase>something has gone wrong - we may look at it<paraphrase>.  From a user perspective the 'Oops' screen left me at a dead end with no indication of what can or should be done next.  This isn't a particulalry good position to leave users of a site.

Answer (score 4):

Helpful to who? There is an internal error dump that the devs would use - the nitty gritty specifics probably aren't important. What were you trying to do? Or post? I have a *hunch*...

Comment: I don't think he's saying reveal details--simply: "user, don't try to resubmit" if that's an appropriate caution (either in general or perhaps according to certain error codes where the problem is more particular to the post than to the state of the system).

Answer (score 1):

No, it couldn't.

Because the next time you encounter this error page, it would say "please resubmit", you would do it and get again the error page telling you "please resubmit" and after doing this ten times in a row, even you would figure out that something is not working properly and you will come back here and post about a problem we did not have before your proposal.